# Trigger using 2 tables

Tags: oracle, triggers

Is it possible to reference a second table within a trigger?

```
create or replace trigger table1
before update of status_code on table1
for each row
declare z_user_id table2.user_id;
begin
    if :new.status_code in (30,40) then
    :new.z_open_01 := nvl(:OLD.z_user_id, nvl(:NEW.z_user_id, :old.z_open_01));
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can, of course, query `table2` and populate a local variable based on the results of that query.  Unless `table2` has a single row, though, you'd need to tell us how `table1` and `table2` are related (and thus how to determine which column from which row in `table2` you're actually trying to read).

Comment: Tables can be joined at all_nbr.  Table1:

Name
--------
WL_KEY
METHOD
MODEL
BUS_UNIT
BOL_NBR
ST_LOCATION
SEASON_ID
UNIT_OF_MEASURE
PLANT_ID
Z_OPEN_01
ALL_NBR
USER
AA_JOB_NBR
COMMENTS
CREATE_DATE
STATUS_CODE
STATUS_DESC
STATUS_TIMESTAMP
TROUBLE_CODE
CURRENT_ACTIVITY

Comment: Table2
Name  
------
ALL_NBR 
SAVED_NAME 
SAVED_DESC 
USER_ID 
CREATEUSER 
GLOBAL_FLAG 
P_TIMECODE

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to grab a user id from Table1 when a condition is meet in Table2, via a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

As to your question: Yes.

The :old and :new constructs only apply to the table that cause the trigger to fire.
The way you have that written you are triggering off of Table1, but your description sounds like you want to grab a value from table one when something in Table2 changes.
But you didn't say what you want to DO with the userid you grab.
If you create a trigger on Table2, read a value from Table1, and save the value in a column in the row that fired the trigger you are gtg. Other scenarios get more complex.

so, based on comments something like:

`create or replace trigger table2
after update of status_code on table2
for each row when (:new.status_code in (30,40))
declare t1_user Table1.user_id%type;
begin
    Select user_id into t1_user from Table1 where <condition>
    :new.z_open_01 := t1_user;
    end if;
end;
/`

setting up whatever condition select the desired user from Table1.

Comment: Based on condition in Table2: :new.status_code in (30,40)
then grab the user_id from Table1 and place in z_open_1, back in Table2.

Comment: So, that sounds like you want to create a trigger on Table2 (with a `when` clause on the status_code) Then do a `select into` from Table1 into a variable that you then set `:new.z_open_1=`variable